# wordpress is_home() || is_index() possible?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a test in my header.php to see whether we are at home to display a hero or not.

```
<?php if ( is_home() && have_posts() ) : ?>
  <div id="hero" class="inner clearfix">
    ...
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

But when the user lands on index.php the hero is not being shown.
apparently there is no is_index() condition, does anyone know how I could test for if its home or index?

Comment: I do have to say I like the design of your site.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `is_front_page()`

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
  <div id="hero" class="inner clearfix">
    ...
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

That should return true if you are on the absolute root of site.

Comment: Stealing? haha, I was actually updating mine and when I saved my edits you had posted lol.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have tried this and it is not working for some reason. home.php and index.php are identical copies and they are the only two pages which are laid out like this so I know that wordpress is serving up either home or index. And yet the hero is not displaying.

Comment: To make it weirder the body has the following class: "single single-post postid-130 single-format-standard logged-in". I deleted single.php. I have no single.php nor page.php

Comment: the only way I am even able to land on this page is by searching my site through google images and clicking on certain images.

Comment: Make sure you set in the reading section under settings of the admin what is set to the home page.

Comment: hmm this looks like it could fix it. But I only have two pages listed, About and Work. I didnt realize I needed to create a static index. I am new to Wordpress

Comment: @user548906: You don't, but if you do in this case the `is_front_page()` would kick in and return true. Try choosing one, and see if it works.

Comment: What is going to be displayed on your home page? Blog listing or static content? If static content I would create a Home page in the pages section and assign that as the sites front page.

Comment: Nope still being led to this stray page

Comment: ok it would probably help if i throw up a link. This is how the front/home/index page should look --> www.getstefan.com

Comment: but if you search my name in google images and click on most any of the graphics displayed in the results, it takes you to a page which looks like the index page minus the hero...

Comment: @user548906: I see `<div id="hero" class="inner clearfix"><!-- Start Logofolio if Home --><div id="imageGallery" class="gallery clearfix">`, why do you think it is not working?

Comment: I dont see that - I see just <div id="top"> and what is within.

Comment: Have you tried removing `&& have_posts()` from the if statement?

Comment: @user548906: Where do you expect it to see? Open up the source code, and check. Make sure you don't have any ad-blocker or something which will block that content. Try using Firebug to see the HTML structure and you will find it. [This is what I see](http://pastebin.com/GYhg3ezJ).

Comment: @Shef, we might have to start commenting under your question. Mines almost filled up. lol Jk

Comment: I have no ad blocker and am using firebug. Within <div id="headerWrap"> I have only <div id="top">. However if I click on home or the logo I see the image gallery.

Comment: When I look at the body I see class of "single" but I have no single.php and if I did, the styling would not be like this. Is this in fact the index.php and if so is it normal to see class of "single" in the body tag?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<?php if ( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && have_posts() ) : ?>
  <div id="hero" class="inner clearfix">
    ...
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

If it still doesn't work, try adding the following just before the `if` statement:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried the wp_reset_query() in combination with is_front_page() and had no luck. Its displaying the design I have created for the front page/home page but its not behaving like its the front/home page.

Answer (score 2):

Try out `is_front_page()` from the [Wordpress conditional tags list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Front_Page).

It is true when you are on the "Front Page" of your wordpress installation, which is:

- The posts page if you have set your front page to your blog/posts
- The page you have designated as your front page, if you are using a page instead of your posts