# keep h1 title on homepage

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have h1 title i put in my home page, but i want to keep it only in my home page. now it shows in

[image]

every single page in the site

im using wordpress and i put it in the header php

```
<?php 
    get_template_part( 'framework/parts/breaking-news' ); // Get Breaking News template 
    tie_banner('banner_below_header' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-below_header">' , '</div>' );
?>
**<h1 style="padding-left:25px; padding-bottom:5px">stiri sportive</h1>**
```

**this is all the header.php code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="PUSf9MdDStKBNkOow1SskiNxuNcQOOzCf7ruKMyjCyE" />
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<?php global $is_IE ?>
<body id="top" <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div class="wrapper-outer">

<?php if( tie_get_option('banner_bg_url') && tie_get_option('banner_bg') ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( tie_get_option('banner_bg_url') ) ?>" target="_blank" class="background-cover"></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="background-cover"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(  tie_get_option( 'mobile_menu_active' ) ): ?>
    <aside id="slide-out">

    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'mobile_menu_search' ) ): ?>
        <div class="search-mobile">
            <form method="get" id="searchform-mobile" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
                <button class="search-button" type="submit" value="<?php if( !$is_IE ) _eti( 'Search' ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                <input type="text" id="s-mobile" name="s" title="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" value="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>';}"  />
            </form>
        </div><!-- .search-mobile /-->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( tie_get_option('mobile_menu_social') ):
        tie_get_social( true , false , 'ttip-none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="mobile-menu" <?php if( !tie_get_option('mobile_menu_hide_icons') ) echo' class="mobile-hide-icons"';?>></div>
    </aside><!-- #slide-out /-->
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php $full_width   =''; if( tie_get_option( 'full_logo' ))     $full_width  = ' full-logo';
          $center_logo  =''; if( tie_get_option( 'center_logo' ))   $center_logo = ' center-logo';
          $theme_layout = 'boxed';

          if( tie_get_option( 'theme_layout' ) == 'full' )      $theme_layout = 'wide-layout';
          if( tie_get_option( 'theme_layout' ) == 'boxed-all' ) $theme_layout = 'boxed-all';
    ?>
    <div id="wrapper" class="<?php echo $theme_layout ?>">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">

        <header id="theme-header" class="theme-header<?php echo $full_width.$center_logo ?>">
            <?php if( tie_get_option( 'top_menu' ) ): ?>
            <div id="top-nav" class="top-nav">
                <div class="container">

            <?php if(tie_get_option( 'top_date' )):
                if( tie_get_option('todaydate_format') ) $date_format = tie_get_option('todaydate_format');
                else $date_format = 'l ,  j  F Y';
            ?>
                <span class="today-date"><?php  echo date_i18n( $date_format , current_time( 'timestamp' ) ); ?></span><?php endif; ?>

                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'top-menu', 'theme_location' => 'top-menu'  ) ); ?>

    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'top_search' ) ): ?>
                    <div class="search-block">
                        <form method="get" id="searchform-header" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
                            <button class="search-button" type="submit" value="<?php if( !$is_IE ) _eti( 'Search' ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            <input class="search-live" type="text" id="s-header" name="s" title="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" value="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>';}"  />
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- .search-block /-->
    <?php endif;
    if( tie_get_option('top_social') ):
        tie_get_social( true , false , 'ttip-none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php tie_language_selector_flags(); ?>

                </div><!-- .container /-->
            </div><!-- .top-menu /-->
            <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="header-content">

        <?php if(  tie_get_option( 'mobile_menu_active' ) ): ?>
            <a id="slide-out-open" class="slide-out-open" href="#"><span></span></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php
if( is_category() || is_single() ){
    if( is_category() ) $category_id = get_query_var('cat') ;
    if( is_single() ){
        $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        if( !empty( $categories[0]->term_id ) )
            $category_id = $categories[0]->term_id ;
    }

    if( !empty( $category_id ) ){
        $tie_cats_options = get_option( 'tie_cats_options' );
        if( !empty( $tie_cats_options[ $category_id ] ) )
            $cat_options = $tie_cats_options[ $category_id ];
    }
}

if( !empty($cat_options['cat_custom_logo']) ){

    $logo_margin ='';
    if( !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin'] ) || !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin_bottom'] ) ){
        $logo_margin = ' style="';
        if( !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin'] ) )
            $logo_margin .= ' margin-top:'.$cat_options['logo_margin'].'px;';
        if( !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin_bottom'] ) )
            $logo_margin .= ' margin-bottom:'.$cat_options['logo_margin_bottom'].'px;';
        $logo_margin .= '"';
    }
 ?>
            <div class="logo"<?php echo $logo_margin ?>>
            <h2>
<?php if( $cat_options['logo_setting'] == 'title' ): ?>
                <a  href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/"><?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                <?php if( !empty($cat_options['logo']) ) $logo = $cat_options['logo'];
                elseif( tie_get_option( 'logo' ) ) $logo = tie_get_option( 'logo' );
                        else $logo = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png';
                ?>
                <a title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo ; ?>" alt="<?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?>" <?php if(  $cat_options['logo_retina_width'] && $cat_options['logo_retina_height'] ) echo 'width="'.$cat_options['logo_retina_width'] .'" height="'.$cat_options['logo_retina_height'].'"'; ?> /><strong><?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?></strong>
                </a>
<?php endif; ?>
            </h2>
            </div><!-- .logo /-->
<?php if( $cat_options['logo_retina'] && $cat_options['logo_retina_width'] && $cat_options['logo_retina_height']): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? true : false;
    if(retina) {
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('src',       '<?php echo $cat_options['logo_retina']; ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('width',     '<?php echo $cat_options['logo_retina_width']; ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('height',    '<?php echo $cat_options['logo_retina_height']; ?>');
    }
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
}else{
    $logo_margin ='';
    if( tie_get_option( 'logo_margin' ) || tie_get_option( 'logo_margin_bottom' ) ){
        $logo_margin = ' style="';
        if( tie_get_option( 'logo_margin' ) )
            $logo_margin .= ' margin-top:'.tie_get_option( 'logo_margin' ).'px;';
        if( tie_get_option( 'logo_margin_bottom' ) )
            $logo_margin .= ' margin-bottom:'.tie_get_option( 'logo_margin_bottom' ).'px;';
        $logo_margin .= '"';
    }
?>
            <div class="logo"<?php echo $logo_margin ?>>
            <?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) echo '<img>'; else echo '<img>'; ?>
<?php if( tie_get_option('logo_setting') == 'title' ): ?>
                <a  href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
                <span><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></span>
                <?php else : ?>
                <?php if( tie_get_option( 'logo' ) ) $logo = tie_get_option( 'logo' );
                        else $logo = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png';
                ?>
                <a title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo ; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" <?php if(  tie_get_option('logo_retina_width') && tie_get_option('logo_retina_height') ) echo 'width="'.tie_get_option('logo_retina_width') .'" height="'.tie_get_option('logo_retina_height').'"'; ?> /><strong><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></strong>
                </a>
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) echo '</img>'; else echo '</img>'; ?>
            </div><!-- .logo /-->
<?php if( tie_get_option( 'logo_retina' ) && tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_width' ) && tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_height' )): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? true : false;
    if(retina) {
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('src',       '<?php echo tie_get_option( 'logo_retina' ); ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('width',     '<?php echo tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_width' ); ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('height',    '<?php echo tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_height' ); ?>');
    }
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
            <?php tie_banner('banner_top' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-top">' , '</div>' ); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
        <?php $stick = ''; ?>
        <?php if( tie_get_option( 'stick_nav' ) ) $stick = ' class="fixed-enabled"' ?>
            <?php if( tie_get_option( 'main_nav' ) ): ?>
            <?php
            //UberMenu Support
            $navID = 'main-nav';
            if ( class_exists( 'UberMenu' ) ){
                $uberMenus = get_option( 'wp-mega-menu-nav-locations' );
                if( !empty($uberMenus) && is_array($uberMenus) && in_array("primary", $uberMenus)) $navID = 'main-nav-uber';
            }?>
            <nav id="<?php echo $navID; ?>"<?php echo $stick; ?>>
                <div class="container">

                <?php if( tie_get_option( 'nav_logo' ) ): ?>
                    <a class="main-nav-logo" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
                        <img src="<?php echo tie_get_option( 'nav_logo' ) ?>" width="195" height="54" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
                    </a>
                <?php endif ?>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-menu', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'walker' => new tie_mega_menu_walker(), 'fallback_cb'=> false) ); ?>
                    <?php if(tie_get_option( 'random_article' )): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?tierand=1" class="random-article ttip" title="<?php _eti( 'Random Article' ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'shopping_cart' ) && function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ):
                        global $woocommerce; ?>
                        <a class="tie-cart ttip" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _eti( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><span class="shooping-count-outer"><?php if( isset( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ) && ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count != 0 ) ){ ?><span class="shooping-count"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ?></span><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span></a>
                    <?php endif ?>

                </div>
            </nav><!-- .main-nav /-->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header><!-- #header /-->

    <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/breaking-news' ); // Get Breaking News template ?>

    <?php tie_banner('banner_below_header' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-below_header">' , '</div>' ); ?>
    <h1 style="padding-left:25px; padding-bottom:5px">stiri sportive</h1>

<?php
$sidebar = '';
if( tie_get_option( 'sidebar_pos' ) == 'left' ) $sidebar = ' sidebar-left';
if( is_singular() || ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && is_woocommerce() ) ){

    $current_ID = $post->ID;
    if( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && is_woocommerce() )   $current_ID = woocommerce_get_page_id('shop');

    $get_meta = get_post_custom( $current_ID );
    if( !empty($get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0]) ){
        $sidebar_pos = $get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0];

        if( $sidebar_pos == 'left' ) $sidebar = ' sidebar-left';
        elseif( $sidebar_pos == 'full' ) $sidebar = ' full-width';
        elseif( $sidebar_pos == 'right' ) $sidebar = ' sidebar-right';
    }
}
if( ( function_exists('is_bbpress') && is_bbpress() && tie_get_option( 'bbpress_full' )) || is_404() ) $sidebar = ' full-width';
?>
    <div id="main-content" class="container<?php echo $sidebar ; ?>">
```

what to add to the code so the title will show only in the homepage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordpress is\_home() || is\_index() possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700001/wordpress-is-home-is-index-possible)

Comment: That's a lot of code ... so have a look at Kens link, have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags and try is_front_page()  is_home()

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `h1` in an if statement using `is_home()` and `is_frontpage()`.

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
  <h1 style="padding-left:25px; padding-bottom:5px">stiri sportive</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`is_home()` returns true or false depending on whether the page being shown is the 'Front Page' or not.

You should consider restructuring things though, so that this forms part of the home page template, rather than being run on every page of your website.

`is_home()` docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

Comment: If this helped you please accept it as the correct answer (the tick under the up & down arrows) so that others can find it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `<h1>` tag with a conditional statement checking whether the page is the homepage or not:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>
  <h1 style="padding-left:25px; padding-bottom:5px">stiri sportive</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

This way, the H1 tag will only show on the website's homepage.